# What are the steps to create a google chart with data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, google-visualization

Please excuse this newbie question but I have not been able to find any tutorials on the web with quite my question.

I  have a long complicated query that outputs data like this:

```
    DECLARE @QA1 TABLE (BeginWeek date, One int, Two int, Three int, Total int)

    INSERT INTO @QA1 
    SELECT '20110612','0','0','5','5' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110626','0','0','8','8' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110703','0','2','12','14' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110710','4','3','12','19' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110717','5','7','14','26' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110724','7','11','14','32' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110731','9','14','14','37' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110807','10','20','17','47' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110814','10','23','20','53' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110821','11','23','20','54' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110828','11','26','25','62' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110904','13','29','25','67' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20110911','20','32','27','79'
```

and I want to be able to display this in HTML as a Google Chart and when I hit reload, it queries the database again and then constructs my chart.

If my query was called `fooQuery`, what steps do I need to follow to be able to dynamically pull this from my database to a webpage ?  Do I have to use PHP ? (if so, I need to install it which would be slightly painful)  Is there any other software ?  Should my SQL query be in the webpage ?  A stored procedure ?

Any web resources with really simple examples would be great !

PS - I am running everything local so I do not need to worry to much about security.

Answer (score 0):

since you have done this in (MS?) SQL server I suggest you download MS Visual studio web express and have a look at the numerous examples available. It allows you to drop a stored procedure on a web page and generates a table for it automatically

Comment: Yes I am using the free MS SQL-Server and I am not familiar with MS Visual Studio web express.  Can it hook into Google Charts ?

Answer (score 0):

The requirements to use Google Charts are basically the same as serving a web page. You need to choose a web server, some language/tool to dynamically construct a web page after querying your database and then include a client side call to Google Charts.

I suggest you start with trying to display your data in a web page (say using Ruby on Rails, JSP, ASP.NET or similar) and then follow some of the excellent tutorials available on the web for using Google Charts.

Comment: Hi,  Well this is kinda the problem, as a newbie to this, there are so many choices.  I am local so my web server is IIS (I think), the language to dynamically create the web page I think is my *big* problem because I am not terribly keen on setting up PHP? I've done some Javascript programming but I don't think that will help ?

Comment: If you want to use IIS, how about using ASP.NET? Do you have any language preferences?